# chrome bug fullscreen background redraw

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have put an all screen-sizes-fits-all, random-with-refresh background image on my site. The effect works well on every browser but **Chrome**. The aggravation happens when you are scrolled down a longer page and leave it via a link and then return to that page, or if you stay on the page and just refresh. **The background will only appear at the moment you scroll**. Works fine if you are at the top of the page.

An example long page of my website:
http://madcoversite.com/ugoi-master.html

Scroll down any length and then refresh. The background will semi-load or not load at all.

My Javascript for the random image:

```
function changeImg(imgNumber)   {
var myImages = ["back100-1-blur.jpg","back150-1-blur.jpg","back150-2-blur.jpg","back050-2-blur.jpg","back050-3-blur.jpg","back050-4-blur.jpg","back050-5-blur.jpg","back050-6-blur.jpg","back050-7-blur.jpg","back200-1-blur.jpg","back200-2-blur.jpg","back300-1-blur.jpg","back100-2-blur.jpg"];
var imgShown = document.body.style.backgroundImage;
var newImgNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length);
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+myImages[newImgNumber]+')';
}
window.onload=changeImg;
```

My CSS for the expanding image to any screen size:

```
body { 
    background: no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML below the end head:

```
<BODY TEXT=000000 LINK=3232CD VLINK=6B238E topmargin=0 onselectstart="return false">
```

I've seen similar discussions involving changing the **fixed** to **scroll**.  There have also been discussions about changing the background-size **cover** variable. Not solving the problem. I was even looking for a creative way to make Chrome scroll one pixel after loading.

Hoping there's a correct way to fix.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your loading your image on the body tag and not with the CSS.  Try putting this code:

```
background-image: url(http://madcoversite.com/back050-5-blur.jpg);">
```

into this:

```
body {
    background: no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Final result:

```
body {
    background-image: url(http://madcoversite.com/back050-5-blur.jpg);
    background: no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

You might need to keep playing with

```
background-image:
```

Until you get it to display the way you want.

Comment: Thanks Oscar. You might be on to something. Maybe Chrome needs that background-image to be designated? I'm wondering how I'll incorporate the random images from the Javascript.

Comment: Since your generating these images from javascript i think the best thing you can do is throw the end result of the javascript into a variable then use that variable in your css file.  I know this is done when using LESS or SASS.  either one of those will let you use variables in CSS.

Comment: Here's a good example of using variables in CSS http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/

Comment: I've decided to take the random out of the mix, and in doing so, have negated the unwanted Chrome effect. I'll swap background images now and then manually. Yes, I'm admitting defeat here, but will reinstitute the above when Chrome decides it's worth their time to join the other browsers. Probably be waiting a while...

Comment: So the new CSS for now:


body { 
  background: url("back050-2-blur.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover; 
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

Comment: Did this ever help you out?  if it did, can you mark as correct?

Comment: Appreciate the help, but as mentioned above, I had to take the random out of the mix and go back to one image. Couldn't get things to work right in Chrome.